# Hyperbolic tiling primer

Tags: soft-question, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm seeking a straightforward explanation and how-to for hyperbolic tiling. A "Hyperbolic Tiling for Dummies," if you will. I want to write my own programs to experiment with and am not interested in these online build-your-own hyperbolic tiling apps.

Comment: What exactly is stopping you right now? Do you need a primer on what hyperbolic tilings are? What algorithms might be good for computing the tilings in a given model of hyperbolic space from given a Fuchsian group action? Links to github repos with sample hyperbolic tiling code?

Comment: @Neal Well, I understand planar tiling, transformations, and mapping. I can take a planar tiling and map it into a crescent, circle, or heart, among others. But when I look at hyperbolic tilings, I don't know if it was created in the circle or mapped into it. It's a complete mystery how it was arrived at. So, to your questions, I know what hyperbolic tilings are, I just don't know how to create them, and I'm not interested in looking at code.